# When should I tell the recruiter my wife is pregnant?

Tags: job-offer, ethics, switzerland

I have recently received an offer for a job at a large company in Lausanne, Switzerland and my wife and I are expecting a child about a month after the proposed start date. I haven't told the recruiter about this yet, but I am considering telling my future boss so we don't get off to a bad start. The company is very generous about paternity benefits and I am worried that if I tell them now (before I've signed the contract), they could push my starting date beyond the baby's due date. In this case I would miss out on any paternity benefits. Is it better to inform my boss or should I keep this to myself for now?

EDIT

So, given what got upvoted here and on other threads, I decided to wait until I had signed my offer. Given the positive reactions from my boss and the recruiter, I don't think I need have worried and I don't think it made a difference. But I think it was the right decision. Everyone is supportive of the four months of leave the company policy entitles me to (even though I will have to take the leave during the probationary period during which they could let me go for any or no reason). I guess it's just a matter of being lucky with a good company and nice coworkers. Thanks to everyone for the helpful inputs.

Comment: There's a good answer at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119173/should-i-disclose-my-intention-to-take-parental-leave-before-accepting-a-job-off?rq=1 but as you are in Switzerland things might be slightly different.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of confirms what I thought already - since I already received an offer, if they were to rescind that upon finding out about my situation, it would seem an awful lot like pregnancy discrimination and likely be illegal...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Four months.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yeah, yikes. It's not what I would have wanted either, I would have favored starting much earlier, or having the baby much later. But unfortunately, it's a bit hard to time these things precisely.

Comment: Have you considered waiving your paternity benefits and informing then right now? A lot of businesses prefer married men with children because they're more "hungry" since they need to provide for their families.

Comment: @nick012000 No I haven't. I've worked for these guys before and made them money, I don't see why I should waive any benefits, for a large corporation...

Comment: @nick012000 please don't encourage people to waive their paternity benefits, for the exact reason you list. It's encouraging the gender pay gap and bias in hiring. OP, enjoy every bit of time with your baby.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the point at which you have a signed and accepted offer. There is no value in doing so beforehand, and however much local laws may protect you, unscrupulous companies will find a way round if they want to.

(Of course, a *really* unscrupulous company may try and do something even after you have a signed and accepted offer but if they're that bad there's probably nothing you can do about it)

Comment: I guess I'm worried that doing that could lead to a bad relationship with my boss o=right out of the gate. But maybe I'm overthinking things...

Comment: Any reasonable boss will understand why you did things this way.